# how to match the values of two fields from two different tables to return another value associated with either one

Tags: sql-server

I am having trouble with SQL server to retrieve a field of values by matching up two fields from different table. 
here is my description:

Table A contains

```
ProductID  ProductName

01         Health insurance1
02         Health insurance2
03         Health insurance3
o4         Car Insurance1
o5         Car Insurance2
06         Property Insurance1
07         Property Insurance2
```

Table B only contains

```
ProductName

Health Insurance1 Yr 10- 11
TTK Health Insurance Yr 2
Health Insurance3 Yr 5-6
Car Insurance1 Yr 3
Car Insurance Yr 4
Car Insurance3 Yr 4-5
Property Insurance Yr 1
Property Insurance3 Yr 5
```

What I want the query to return is the ProductID from the table A be appeared and aligned exactly with productName in Table B as it is in table A. Notice that the values from both productName fields are not exactly the same but look very similar.

Following is the script I tried using LIKE operator, but it returned me with redundant productID since it seems that the LIKE operator does not process anything after the 'insurance'.

```
select distinct 
       a.productID, b.productname 
from
      tableA a,
      tableB b
where 
      b.productname like '%' + a.productname+ '%'
      or a.productname like '%' + b.productname+ '%'
order by a.prodID
```

Please help me solve this problem. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: So the only link between tables A and B is that the ProductName is similar?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
SELECT  distinct 
        a.productID, b.productname 
FROM    tableA a
        INNER JOIN tableB b
            ON b.productname LIKE '%' + a.productname+ '%'
ORDER BY a.prodID
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Hey Jade, the code you provided still didn't return me the values I wanted. Same ProductIDs are stilled duplicated regardless of the difference among productNames. For instance, only ProductID 01(table A) will be assigned to all products that contain "Health Insurance"(table B) regardless of the remaining content such as "YR 1-2"; and ID 02 and 03 (table A) will never be assigned for any products with content containing "Health Insurance" (table B).

Comment: Can you post what result you expected base on your above sample to make it clearer.